# Upsert (on conflict) vs Read before Write performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

Everytime a logged in user visits one of my webpages, I add a row to a table of (user_id, page_id) to mark that this page was visited where (user_id, page_id) is the primary key in this table.
Of course, if the user comes to this page again then the row already exists so a new one doesn't need to be added.

I currently use a postgres ON CONFLICT clause to first try writing and if there's a conflict then I do nothing since the row already exists.
But I'm worried that because this write action is happening on every page visit that it's adding unnecessary load to the DB.

Is this thinking correct? If so, then instead of doing the upsert ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING, should I instead do a READ to check if this (user_id, page_id) already exists in the table, and if not, THEN only do the insert?

The benefit of the upsert ON CONFLICT is that it's just one single DB query. The second method of read before write would be 2 DB calls which would be slower since it has to go over the network. But the drawback of the first method is that it's doing a write on every page visit (or is it not actually considered a write since 99% of the time it will result in a conflict?).

Which way should I be following?

Comment: There is no write for conflicts, per here [ON CONFLICT](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries): '... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING simply avoids inserting a row as its alternative action. ...'

Comment: So it doesn't first /try/ to write and then if it fails undoes the write?

Comment: '...  simply avoids inserting a row ...' pretty much explains it. If you want more information look at here [Source](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/executor/nodeModifyTable.c;h=f450e4d80ad33bfe58923fe514e887491c66ae3d;hb=6daf725a9c66e880fd76d25279ce00710535e030) line 551. Then line 557. The only side effect I know of is that if you have `serial` or `identity` column using a `sequence` that sequence will be incremented.

Comment: Did you link to the wrong page above? That page doesn't say anything about on conflict.

Comment: It is the source code that deals with this. If you go go lines 551 and 570(I got that wrong in above) in the file you will see that no `INSERT` is done if `DO NOTHING` is specified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a separate network round trip, you could package it up into one statement.  However, in my hands the ON CONFLICT is slightly faster than the "pre-read" with a two-column key, and generates no extra IO.  Tested using pgbench with the custom transactions (once the table is fully populated with all 1e6 rows):

```
\set a random(1, 1000)
\set b random(1, 1000)
insert into foo (a,b) values (:a,:b) on conflict do nothing;
```

versus

```
\set a random(1, 1000)
\set b random(1, 1000)
insert into foo (a,b) select :a,:b where not exists (select 1 from foo where a=:a and b=:b)
```

Plus the pre-read might be subject to race conditions.